# Reverse HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior and initialize to hide state android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, material-components-android

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a RecyclerView and a Fab button.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipeChatRoomRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/chatRoomRecycler"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="true"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
                </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/bottomScrollFab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/swipeChatRoomRecycler"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    app:fabSize="mini" />
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The recyclerView is set as below

```
viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity).apply {
            orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            stackFromEnd = false
            reverseLayout = true
        }
```

What i want to achieve is

1. At the launch of the activity i want the `bottomScrollFab` to be invisible since the recycler is scrolled in the end as by default
2. I want to achieve the exact reverse behaviour, meaning that i want the Fab to be shown when recycler is not onScroll and to be hidden when recycler is onScroll

How can i do those two things?

Comment: You can achieve this if you have AppBarLayout with Toolbar that has `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`. The behavior is the Toolbar is expanded by default while the BottomNav is collapsed, upon scrolling if the Toolbar collapse the BottomNav expand.

Answer (score 0):

Well up to now i have created a custom Behaviour which changes the alpha when the recycler is scrolled. It works pretty fine

```
class ReverseHideViewOnScrollBehaviour(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>(context, attributeSet) {

    override fun layoutDependsOn(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: View, dependency: View): Boolean {
        return dependency is RecyclerView
    }

    override fun onDependentViewChanged(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: View, dependency: View): Boolean {
        val yPercentage = getViewOffsetFromRecycler(parent, child)
        val diff = 100.0f - yPercentage
        child.alpha = 1 - diff
        return true
    }

    private fun getViewOffsetFromRecycler(parent: CoordinatorLayout, view: View): Float{
        var percentage = 100f
        val dependencies = parent.getDependencies(view)

        dependencies.forEach { dependency ->
            if (dependency is SwipeRefreshLayout) {
                val recycler = (dependency.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.chatRoomRecycler))
                val offset: Int = recycler.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
                val extent: Int = recycler.computeVerticalScrollExtent()
                val range: Int = recycler.computeVerticalScrollRange()
                percentage = if (range - extent == 0) 100f else 100.0f * offset / (range - extent).toFloat()
            }
        }

        return percentage
    }
}
```

So the FloatinActionButton

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/bottomScrollFab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                    app:layout_behavior=".ui.views.ReverseHideViewOnScrollBehaviour"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/swipeChatRoomRecycler"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    app:fabSize="mini" />
```